# Do I have to redo my ghusl if there was still semen pouring out?

Tags: fiqh, taharah, ghusl

Lately I went to perform ghusl al-Janabah (very early after intercourse). 
But when I finished it I realized that there was still some semen pouring out.

Is my ghusl valid or do I have to redo it in such a case?

Otherwise asked: Do I regain taharah only if I the semen was entirely washed away or is it sufficient to perform ghusl by washing ones body?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned liquid/emission is either madhi, in case ejaculation of semen *not* taking place and is due to sexual arousal, or, wadhi, in case of the ejaculation of semen taking place. In both case the liquid is pure/tahir and you do not have to redo your ghusul or purify yourself.

It is also recommended to urinate after ejaculation of semen.

Comment: A reference would be appreciated.